# Understanding LAPACK calls in C++ with a simple example

Tags: c++, fortran, lapack

I am a beginner with LAPACK and C++/Fortran interfacing. I need to solve linear equations and eigenvalues problems using LAPACK/BLAS on Mac OS-X Lion. OS-X Lion provides optimized BLAS and LAPACK libraries (in /usr/lib) and I am linking these libraries instead of downloading them from netlib.

My program (reproduced below) is compiling and running fine, but it is giving me wrong answers. I have researched in the web and Stackoverflow and the issue may have to deal with how C++ and Fortran store arrays in differing formats (row major vs Column major). However, as you will see in my example, the simple array for my example should look identical in C++ and fortran. Anyway here goes.

Lets say we want to solve the following linear system:

x + y = 2

x - y = 0

The solution is (x,y) = (1,1). Now I tried to solve this using Lapack as follows

```
// LAPACK test code

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
extern "C" void dgetrs(char *TRANS, int *N, int *NRHS, double *A, 
                      int *LDA, int *IPIV, double *B, int *LDB, int *INFO );

int main()
{
    char trans = 'N';
    int dim = 2;    
    int nrhs = 1;
    int LDA = dim;
    int LDB = dim;
    int info;

    vector<double> a, b;

    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(-1);

    b.push_back(2);
    b.push_back(0);

    int ipiv[3];


    dgetrs(&trans, &dim, &nrhs, & *a.begin(), &LDA, ipiv, & *b.begin(), &LDB, &info);


    std::cout << "solution is:";    
    std::cout << "[" << b[0] << ", " << b[1] << ", " << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Info = " << info << std::endl; 

    return(0);
}
```

This code was compiled as follows:

`g++ -Wall -llapack -lblas lapacktest.cpp`

On running this, however, I get the solution as (-2,2) which is obviously wrong. I have tried all combination of row/column re-arrangement of my matrix `a`. Also observe the matrix representation of `a` should be identical in row and column formats. I think getting this simple example to work will get me started with LAPACK and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what lapack library are you using and is it 64 bit code?

Comment: I am using the /usr/lib/liblapack.dylib and /usr/lib/libblas.dylib that is natively present on Mac OS-X Lion. I have not installed any external LAPACK/BLAS libraries.

Comment: In you example, you are solving a symmetric matrix so whether you have row-major or column-major, you won't see any difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to *factor* the matrix (by calling `dgetrf`) before you can solve the system using `dgetrs`.  Alternatively, you can use the `dgesv` routine, which does both steps for you.

By the way, you don't need to declare the interfaces yourself, they are in the Accelerate headers:

```
// LAPACK test code

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char trans = 'N';
    int dim = 2;    
    int nrhs = 1;
    int LDA = dim;
    int LDB = dim;
    int info;

    vector<double> a, b;

    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(-1);

    b.push_back(2);
    b.push_back(0);

    int ipiv[3];

    dgetrf_(&dim, &dim, &*a.begin(), &LDA, ipiv, &info);
    dgetrs_(&trans, &dim, &nrhs, & *a.begin(), &LDA, ipiv, & *b.begin(), &LDB, &info);


    std::cout << "solution is:";    
    std::cout << "[" << b[0] << ", " << b[1] << ", " << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Info = " << info << std::endl; 

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Stephen, thanks so much. This works. By the way, I hope you dont mind answering two follow-up questions: (1) Where can I find documentation of LAPACK which specifies all the dependencies (like using dgetrf before dgetrs). For example, I constructed my original program by looking up the information in the dgetrs() function in Netlib. However, it didnt say that I first had to factor using dgetrf. (2) I am assuming that to use Accelerate framework, I just compile using -framework Accelerate. Is that correct? Thanks once again.

Comment: @RDK: You can either compile with -framework Accelerate or link directly against LAPACK/BLAS as you have been doing (you end up getting the same LAPACK library either way).  Looking at `dgetrs` on netlib actually *does* tell you that you need `dgetrf`: "DGETRS solves a system of linear equations with a general N-by-N matrix A using the LU factorization computed by DGETRF."  However, a better reference would be the LAPACK user's guide, which is available in html on netlib, and also in a cheap dead tree form.

Comment: You are right. It does say so. By bad and apologies. I guess I have to read more carefully in the future. I am going for the cheap dead tree form, as my colleagues will also be interested in a reference at hand. Thanks once again for your patience and responses.

Comment: @RDK: no need to apologize, that text is confusing at best.

Answer (score 10):

For those who don't want bother with the Accelerate Framework, I provide the code of Stephen Canon (thanks to him, of course) with nothing but pure library linking

```
// LAPACK test code
//compile with: g++ main.cpp -llapack -lblas -o testprog

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void dgetrf_(int* dim1, int* dim2, double* a, int* lda, int* ipiv, int* info);
extern "C" void dgetrs_(char *TRANS, int *N, int *NRHS, double *A, int *LDA, int *IPIV, double *B, int *LDB, int *INFO );

int main()
{
    char trans = 'N';
    int dim = 2;
    int nrhs = 1;
    int LDA = dim;
    int LDB = dim;
    int info;

    vector<double> a, b;

    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(-1);

    b.push_back(2);
    b.push_back(0);

    int ipiv[3];

    dgetrf_(&dim, &dim, &*a.begin(), &LDA, ipiv, &info);
    dgetrs_(&trans, &dim, &nrhs, & *a.begin(), &LDA, ipiv, & *b.begin(), &LDB, &info);


    std::cout << "solution is:";
    std::cout << "[" << b[0] << ", " << b[1] << ", " << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Info = " << info << std::endl;

    return(0);
}
```

And about the manual, there's a full PDF version available at Intel's website. Here's a sample of their HTML documentation.

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-A02DB70F-9704-42A4-9071-D409D783D911.htm

Comment: This code example was very helpful. Helped me recognize that my copy of the LAPACK libraries wasn't linked to my project correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use LAPACK from C++ you might want to have a look a [FLENS](http://flens.sf.net).  It defines low- and high-level interfaces to LAPACK but also re-implements some LAPACK functions.

With the low-level FLENS-LAPACK interface you can use your own matrix/vector types (if they have a LAPACK conform memory layout).  Your call of `dgetrf` would look like that:

```
info = lapack::getrf(NoTrans, dim, nrhs, a.begin(), LDA, ipiv);
```

and for `dgetrs`

```
lapack::getrs(NoTrans, dim, nrhs, a.begin(), LDA, ipiv, b.begin(), LDB);
```

So the low-level FLENS-LAPACK functions are overloaded with respect to the element types.  Consequently LAPACK function `sgetrs`, `dgetrs`, `cgetrs`, `zgetrs` are in the low-level interface of FLENS-LAPACK `lapack::getrs`.  You also pass parameters by value/reference and not as pointer (e.g. `LDA` instead of `&LDA`).

If you use the FLENS matrix-types you can code it as

```
info = lapack::trf(NoTrans, A, ipiv);
if (info==0) {
    lapack::trs(NoTrans, A, ipiv, b);
}
```

Or you just use the LAPACK driver function `dgesv`

```
lapack::sv(NoTrans, A, ipiv, b);
```

Here a [list of FLENS-LAPACK](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/lapack/lapack.html) driver functions.

Disclaimer: Yes, FLENS is my baby! That means I coded about 95% of it and every line of code was worth it.

Comment: FLENS looks like a great way to interface LAPACK/C++. I will be sure to check this out.