# Numerically solve a matrix equation in the optimal way

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, lapack, armadillo

Given a complex square matrix **G** and a square matrix **M**, which I can compute quickly from **G**, I need to calculate efficiently the matrix **G'** defined by the matrix equation **G'** ⋅ **M**<sup>**⊤**</sup> = **G** in my C++ program.  Afterwards the original **G** can be discarded.

Since my experience with numerical linear algebra is limited I have so far relied on the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library, which has very nice syntax and can provide good performance. My approach here would then be to take the transpose of both sides of the equation and solve the problem 
**M** ⋅ (**G'**)<sup>**⊤**</sup> = **G**<sup>**⊤**</sup> by calling

```
using namespace arma;
G = trans(solve(M, trans(G));
```

But if I have understood the heavily template-based code correctly, this would involve actually performing the transpositions and copying data around the LAPACK routine [cgesv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d16/group__complex_g_esolve.html#gaa9e9aeee4df582bfee679de7defb8e68). Of course these are O(N<sup>2</sup>) operations compared to the O(N<sup>3</sup>) of the actual linear solver, but I'd still rather avoid them in this case.

I have never used LAPACK directly up to now, but would there be the possibility to gain performance by directly calling a LAPACK routine without having to actually carry out the transpositions? Or would you suggest a different approach?

---

Comment: How big are those matrices? If you're talking about something larger than 10x10, the transposition will be negligible compared to linear solver.

Comment: There is no good reason to resort to direct LAPACK calls for this. You said it yourself, the transposition is extremely cheap compared to the solver, so you're getting a performance bonus that may be too small to measure in return for making your code a lot less readable. Using LAPACK directly from C/C++ is rather messy.

Comment: Also take a look at the Eigen library: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html I *think* they use some template magic that means the transposition is never actually computed, it just provides different accessor routines to the next operation (some kind of decomposition for the solver). I don't know much about armadillo, but maybe they do that as well?

Comment: The matrices would be between 64x64 and 1024x1024 for now, potentially bigger later, if I manage to further optimize some other parts of the algorithms. You are right for sure that performance gains would be marginal at this point. This is more a matter of principle (and maybe wasted energy...): It just feels so _unnecessary_ to do the transpositions.

Comment: @us2012 Eigen is definitely a promising library as well.  For now I have relied on Armadillo mostly because the major parts of the computations can be done by the Intel MKL, which provides some degree of parallelization and _should_ be the best-optimized code for the cluster of Xeon CPUs my programs run on.

Comment: A matter of what principle exactly? Premature optimization? I'm only partly joking ;) . There's something else that catches my eye though, you say that `M` can be computed quickly from `G`. Could this not lead to an easier solution of your system?

Comment: With "quickly" I meant O(N^2). I have spent some thought on whether there is an easier solution, but could not find anything better than O(N^3). This might be another question, though, maybe on the mathematics sister site..

Answer (score 0):

I have once provided a C++ code for lapack. Take a look at my answer which provides an example on how to use lapack from the original Fortran library.

[Understanding LAPACK calls in C++ with a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112135/understanding-lapack-calls-in-c-with-a-simple-example/18688774#18688774)

Comment: While this is related, I was rather looking for lapack advise for this specific problem

Comment: In that link you have a manual and you have an example on how to solve general matrices. With all due respect, but what do you need exactly? Should I solve it for you? What do you need more than an example with different dimensionality? I'm very puzzled by your answer.